# Why do I get a different result with partial fractions than with parts?

Tags: calculus

When integrating,

$ \displaystyle\int  \frac{x}{(x +3)^{2} } \space dx$,

with partial fraction decomposition I get,

$\ln | x + 3 | +  \frac{3}{x+3} + C  $.

However when I use integration by parts I get,

$\ln | x + 3 | -  \frac{x}{x+3} + C  .$

How is this possible? Is it possible that I have made a mistake? Thanks
in advance for any help.

Comment: as lab points out the difference is explained by the constant of integration.

Answer (score 4):

Observe that  $$\frac3{x+3}=\frac{x+3-x}{x+3}=-\frac x{x+3}+1$$

i.e., they differ by only constant so have the same derivative